# How to track memory for a python script

Tags: python, memory-management, stackless

We have a system that only has one interpreter. Many user scripts come through this interpreter. We want put a cap on each script's memory usage. There is only process, and that process invokes tasklets for each script. So since we only have one interpreter and one process, we don't know a way to put a cap on each scripts memory usage. What is the best way to do this

Comment: "We have a system that only has one interpreter".  Save yourself a lot of work and get a real system with more than one interpreter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that it's possible at all. Your questions implies that the memory used by your tasklets is completly separated, which is probably not the case. Python is optimizing small objects like integers. As far as I know, for example each `3` in your code is using the same object, which is not a problem, because it is imutable. So if two of your tasklets use the same (small?) integer, they are already sharing memory. ;-)

Comment: Well even if he used two different python interpreters they'd still share the code for the dlls (on Windows at least; I assume same is true for all other OSes?) ;) So defining a "private workingset" for each thread or so is possible - the question is if python has the capabilities to do it. Probably not.

Answer (score 0):

Memory is separated at OS process level. There's no easy way to tell to which tasklet and even to which thread does a particular object belong.

Also, there's no easy way to add a custom bookkeeping allocator that would analyze which tasklet or thread is is allocating a piece of memory and prevent from allocating too much. It would also need to plug into garbage-collection code to discount objects which are freed.

*Unless you're keen to write a custom Python interpreter, using a process per task is your best bet.*

You don't even need to kill and respawn the interpreters every time you need to run another script. Pool several interpreters and only kill the ones that overgrow a certain memory threshold after running a script. Limit interpreters' memory consumption by means provided by OS if you need.

If you need to share large amounts of common data between the tasks, use shared memory; for smaller interactions, use sockets (with a messaging level above them as needed).

Yes, this might be slower than your current setup. But from your use of Python I suppose that in these scripts you don't do any time-critical computing anyway.